# C++ Build order?

Tags: c++, gradle

Trying to build C++ multipart project. I have this in settings.gradle:

```
include 'Common', 'Base'
```

Gradle build this in alphabetical order:

1. Base
2. Common

I need the opposite:

1. Common
2. Base

Comment: I didn't even think about building C++ projects in gradle and I've never used gradle but did you try to swap the order to `include 'Base', 'Common'`?

Comment: Sure, and gradle documentation explicitly say that build is always in alphabetical order.

Comment: "I need the opposite". Why?

Comment: Because 'Base' depends on results of 'Common'

Comment: Then you probably need to add the dependency to your build file.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in each gradle file you need to add dependency (i.e. projects you want to be built before this one)

```
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':Common')
    }
```

and then gradle creates correct build graph.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the answer. Build is still in alphabetical order. ```Tasks to be executed: [task ':compileDebugCpp', task ':Base:compileDebugWindowsX86-64Cpp', task ':Common:compileDebugWindowsX86-64Cpp', task ':Common:linkDebugWindowsX86-64', task ':Base:linkDebugWindowsX86-64', task ':linkDebug', task ':assemble', task ':check', task ':build', task ':Base:assemble', task ':Base:check', task ':Base:build', task ':Common:assemble', task ':Common:finalize', task ':Common:check', task ':Common:build']```